# can I use windows 8 font （Segoe UI）for my web app?

Tags: windows-8, web, fonts

plus, how to know whether I can use any font for app development purpose? I mean develop app for commercial use, like develop app for client.

any free font website to recommend?

Comment: Please note that recommendations are off topic for this site because they can attract spam. If you want your question to be on-topic for the site, you may want to remove the second part (the recommendation).

Comment: An alternative in 2019  -- From https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-alternatives-to-Segoe-UI-Light-font/answer/Joe-Pemberton-1
 -- Goto:  https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans
 Use 'SELECT THIS FONT' on top   -- copy paste your code given both <link ..>   and   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

Answer (score 4):

Segoe UI requires a license if you want to include it as a web font for commercial use in a site. Consider a font such as Open Sans as a free alternative or purchase the license. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

Answer (score 3):

There is now an open-source variant of Segoe UI, called Selawik. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/winjs/bootstrap-winjs/tree/5a3c1341190e7585fd550e01cfded50ae4e8a4c7/src/fonts).
It isn't available yet as a web font, but I think it's only a matter of time before it gets uploaded to a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

For distribution of fonts like Segoe UI see [Microsoft Typography](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331) site. In terms of free fonts, there are many, many sites you can find via a Bing search. Some font are free for personal use, some free for commercial use, some require attribution (often via Creative Commons) and others are fee-based.